# ~/.ssh/config deposited hosts not known

Tags: ssh

I a  experiencing some trouble using ssh, which I can't figure out by myself.
My `~/.ssh/config` file looks like this:

```
Host server
HostName            xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
User                user
ForwardX11          yes
LocalForward        8000 127.0.0.1:8000
LocalForward        6080 127.0.0.1:6080
LocalForward        8022 192.168.122.100:22
LocalForward        7777 192.168.122.100:7777
Compression         yes
ServerAliveInterval 5
ServerAliveCountMax 3
```

Manuel connect using `ssh user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` works fine, yet `ssh server` does not because zsh "could not resolve hostname". 
Do you have any ideas? 
Does this problem occour because I use zsh? 
Since the ssh gets called by a lot of bash scripts I am forced to use the config file.

Comment: `ssh -vvv IP` and `ssh -vvv server` will give you more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like "server" is not being resolved by DNS.

On the system you are sshing from, add something like this to /etc/hosts:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx    server.domain.com        server
```

Then try ssh again.

Comment: When i add "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx server" the command "ssh server" i get a timeout. I guess the command gets extended to "ssh localhost@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" instead of "user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx".

Comment: Does "ping" work: `ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` and `ping server` ?

Comment: ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx works, yet ping server shows "unknown host"

Comment: i used the alias ´server=user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx´ but if a script calls ssh server it uses localuser@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.

Comment: If ping <servername> doesn't work, you have a problem with name resolution, not a problem with ssh.  If you can fix the problem so that ping works, that should fix it for ssh as well.